Using the Contraction Principle, show that the sequence given by $x_{n+1}=\ln(\sqrt{1 + x_n^2})$ is convergent and find its limit.
Show (using the Contraction Principle) that the sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ given by $x_{n+1}=\ln(\sqrt{1 + x_n^2})$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x_0 = 1$ is convergent and find its limit.
Ps. I wrote $f(x)=\ln(\sqrt{1 + x^2})$ then used its derivative, I obtained $f'(x)= \frac{x}{1+x^2}$ and so I concluded $f$ is convergent for $x>0$. Then I tried to use the fixed point equation $x=f(x)$, but didn't get a nice result.

The fixed point is clearly $0$.

From $x_{n+1} = \phi(x_n)$ and $x_n = \phi(x_{n-1})$ we have $x_{n+1}-x_n = \phi'(\zeta)(x_n-x_{n-1})$ now if $|\phi'(\zeta)|<1$ then $|x_{n+1}-x_n| < |x_n-x_{n-1}|$

Given $f(x)=\ln(\sqrt{1 + x^2})$ then used its derivative to obtained $f'(x)= \frac{x}{1+x^2} \leq 1/2 ~~\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. Now by MVT theorem we can write, $\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y} = f^{'}(c) \leq 1/2 \implies |f(x) - f(y)| \leq (1/2)|x - y| ~~\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. So, according to the Banach contraction principle, $f$ has a fixed point.
But to prove your result, we need to observe some inequalities:
First of all  for $c = 1/2$, $|x_{n} - x_{n-1}| = |f(x_{n-1}) - f(x_{n-2})| \leq c|x_{n-1} - x_{n-2}| 
\\= c|f(x_{n-2}) - f(x_{n-3})| 
\\\leq c^{2}|x_{n-2} - x_{n-3}|
\\ \vdots
\\ \leq c^{n-1}|x_{1} - x_{0}|$
By using this result, we have for $m < n$,
$|x_{m} - x_{n}| \leq |x_{m} - x_{m+1}| + |x_{m+1} - x_{m+2}| + \cdots + |x_{n-1} - x_{n}|
\\ \leq(c^{m}+c^{m+1} + \cdots + c^{n-1})|x_{1} - x_{0}|
\\ \leq \frac{c^{m}|x_{1} - x_{0}|}{1-c}$
This implies $x_{n}$ is a Cauchy sequence in a complete metric space $\mathbb{R}$, so it has to be convergent.
